# File upload limit SAS OnDemand

Tags: sas

I have a .dat file that is 1.08 GB that I am trying to upload to SAS OnDemand (University Edition) but I am unable to do so since there is an upload limit of 1GB I believe?

Is there a way to "split" the .dat file into 2 smaller files, or any other way to work around this problem?

Comment: Can you compress the file with ZIP or GZIP?  That should make it smaller than the limit.  Can you post it one a file sharing site and download via a URL with SAS code instead of uploading via the user interface?

Comment: I cannot do the second method as this file has confidential data. When I tried compressing the data with ZIP or GZIP, I could upload the file. However, I ended up getting characters that were invalid. When I used a different dataset (that was smaller than 1GB without compressing it), the SAS code worked fine. Would there be a way to upload the large file without compressing it?

Comment: I'm confused. Compressing shouldn't cause any issues or corrupt any data. You can uncompress it using SAS to get to the original file with the `filename zip` access method.

Comment: You might have to watch out when using the ZIP fileref engine if the file contains a byte order mark, BOM, at the start.  The ZIP file engine might cause SAS to treat that as part of the data.  You could first copy the file out of the ZIP file before trying to read it.